# Как визуализировать матрицу состоящую из градации серого с помощью SFML

Tags: c++, изображения, матрицы, sfml

Eсть матрица 256x256, состоящая из значений double от 0 до 1, где 0 - это серый, а 1 это белый. Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама матрица в программе задаётся следующим образом:

```
std::array<std::array<long double, 256>, 256>
```

Как получить из этого картинку в виде такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думал в сторону преобразования этих градаций к виду: 1->255 и 0->128. И использовать следующий код для сохранения картинки, но, видимо, у меня не достаточно знаний, чтобы понять что я делаю не так:

```
sf::Image image;
image.create(256, 256, sf::Color::Black);
for (size_t x = 0; x < 256; ++x)
{
    for (size_t y = 0; y < 256; ++y)
    {
        image.setPixel(x, y, rgb(arr[x][y], arr[x][y], arr[x][y]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему 1->255 и 0->128, а не 1->255 и 0->0?

Comment: @Harry я предполагал, что буду работать с серыми тонами, но по факту допустимы и чёрные 
 тона, как указали вы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
constexpr auto convert(double value) -> std::uint32_t
{
    constexpr double        src_min = 0.0;
    constexpr double        src_max = 1.0;
    constexpr std::uint32_t dst_min = 0;
    constexpr std::uint32_t dst_max = 255;

    const auto normalized = static_cast<std::uint8_t>((dst_max - dst_min)
                          * ((value - src_min) / (src_max - src_min))
                          + dst_min);

    std::uint32_t color {};
    color |= static_cast<std::uint32_t>(normalized) << 8U;
    color |= static_cast<std::uint32_t>(normalized) << 16U;
    color |= static_cast<std::uint32_t>(normalized) << 24U;

    return color;
}
```

Здесь происходит нормализация значения из отрезка [0.0; 1.0] на отрезок [0; 255]:

```
const auto normalized = static_cast<std::uint8_t>((dst_max - dst_min)
                      * ((value - src_min) / (src_max - src_min))
                      + dst_min);
```

А здесь мы получаем новое значение цвета в пространстве RGBA, упакованное в `std::uint32_t` (у `Color` есть [конструктор](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Color.php#a5449f4b2b9a78230d40ce2c223c9ab2e), который принимает не отдельно цветовые компоненты RGB, а целое число, где каждый байт определяет такой компонент). Правда, я мог напутать с порядком, если что, поменяете.

```
std::uint32_t color {};
color |= static_cast<std::uint32_t>(normalized) << 8U;
color |= static_cast<std::uint32_t>(normalized) << 16U;
color |= static_cast<std::uint32_t>(normalized) << 24U;
```

Ну а дальше, собственно, Ваш код:

```
sf::Image image;
image.create(256, 256, sf::Color::Black);
for (size_t x = 0; x < 256; ++x)
{
    for (size_t y = 0; y < 256; ++y)
    {
        image.setPixel(x, y, sf::Color(convert(arr[x][y])));
    }
}
```

Comment: Эту будет работать, однако из за того, что большая чать матрицы имеет маленькие значения, после отображения множества (0 1) на множество (0 255) теряется часть информация (0.0003232 -> 0 ; 0.00345 -> 0). Цвет у них будет у обоих чёрный, но числа отличаются а значит и оттенок тоже должен чуть чуть отличаться. Это та проблема с которой мне предстоит ещё столкнуться.

Comment: @АндрейШестаков, допустим. Тогда изначально Ваш вопрос в чем был? Того, что Вы написали в комментарии, в исходном вопросе нет.